# Custom event in a winform usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am adding a usercontrol dynamically to a winform. The user control has a custom event.

```
form_load()
{
ucUpdateProgress ucUP = new ucUpdateProgress();
ucUP.customEvent += new EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>(ucUP_customEvent);
this.Controls.Add(new ucUpdateProgress());
}
```

I am calling this event when the user click the cancel button. But the customevent's value is null. Why is that? Whats wrong with my code?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomEventArgs cEA = new CustomEventArgs(true);
        customEvent(sender, cEA);
    }
```

Thanks,
Syd

Comment: don't know, I'd have to see more of the code. Like the code for the `CustomEventArgs` constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be

```
this.Controls.Add(ucUP)
```

not

```
this.Controls.Add(new ucUpdateProgress());
```

Comment: How did I miss that? anyway thank you very much. Spent almost 10 mins scratching my head on this.